How do I change the change the layout of view focused by external keyboard?
I have a list item that the user will be navigating through using an external keyboard. By default, scrolling to an item with the keyboard will dim the view slightly, but too subtly. I would like to change the view to have a marigold border in this event:
fun MultiAcctCard(
configuration: Configuration,
account: Account,
onClick: (Account) -> Unit,
) {
val context = LocalContext.current

var borderColor by remember { mutableStateOf(context.getColor(R.color.transparent)) }
Card(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(top = 15.dp, start = 15.dp, end = 15.dp)
        .then(
            if (configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
                Modifier.height(185.dp) else Modifier.wrapContentHeight()
        )
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .clickable(
            onClick = { onClick(account) }
        )
        .focusable(true)
        .onFocusChanged {
            borderColor =
                if (it.isFocused) context.getColor(R.color.marigold) else context.getColor(R.color.transparent)
        }
        .border(width = 2.dp, color = Color(borderColor).padding(2.dp), shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 8.dp)),
    backgroundColor = Color.White,
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(corner = CornerSize(7.dp))
)
}

The above code does not show the border at all. There appears to be multiple definitions of "focus", but I would like to listen exclusively for the one that deals with scrolling via keyboard. Is that possible?
